# How to plot 3D doble interaction

Tags: r, 3d, interaction

I have a `GLM` with two interactions (`A:B` and `A:B^2`)

The model looks like this:

```
model = X~A+B+B^2+A:B+A:B^2
```

The outcome of the model shows one interaction positive and the other negative. Both are significant. How can I combine the effects of both interactions in the same 3D surface plot?

I've plotted only one interaction at a time, using:

```
library(visreg)
visreg2d(model,x="A", y="B", plot.type='persp',scale='response',
         col="white", border="black",
         theta=60, phi=10, r=10)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You do need to realize that B^2 as a term in a formula is not the same as values that would result from B*B.  Assuming you fix that conceptual difficulty, preferably by using `poly()` and are using `glm` and not `GLM`, then just use `predict`. The ggplot system doesn't do pseudo-3d plots so you would use either persp or lattice::wireframe. The plot3D package is also very capable.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. That should be useful to others. Even better would be if you could post a complete example as an answer, ... and then you can checkmark it.